# How to hedge x gamma in callable prdc?

Tags: exotics, structured-finance

How do you hedge the short rates - fx cross gamma in a callable PRDC (Power Reverse Dual Currency note) ?

Comment: Are these structures still being traded? I thought everyone toned them back about a decade ago and lost interest in them... They're back?

Answer (score 3):

You generally can’t.  There aren’t enough suppliers.  Therefore you end up living with it , which means that the correlation between US swap rates and USDJPY Fx can get very high since many dealers have it.